# Writing a function that returns a list with the name and content of subfolders in r

Tags: r, list, function, directory

I'm trying to write a function that displays the subfolder names and contents. I have the following written code. However when I call the function, only the names of the subfolders are returned.

```
My_file <- function (Folder_name){

  My_list <- list.files(path =  "/Users/user/Desktop/task/Data/Data")
  
return(My_list)

}
```

The folder "Data" contains 2 subfolders "House" and "Cars". I want the function to return the name of the subfolder and the contents of each subfolder.

For example output should be:

```
$House 

Bungalow.extension

$Car 

Porsche.extension
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
path =  "/Users/user/Desktop/task/Data/Data"
lapply(list.files(path), function(i) list.files(paste0(path, "/", i)))
```

**Edit:**
Suppose this is your current  path :

```
path = "/Users/user/Desktop/task/Data"
```

You want to look into `Folder_name` (which is a folder inside `path`) and get the list of subfolders as well as their contents.

```
My_file <- function (Folder_name){
  newpath <- paste0(path, "/", Folder_name)
  lapply(list.files(newpath), function(i) list.files(paste0(newpath, "/", i)))
}
```

Try `My_file("Data")`.

Comment: I need to write as a function that can return the name of the subfolder and the contents of each subfolder.

Comment: What are the arguments of your function? In your example, it is `Folder_name`, but you are nowhere using `Folder_name` inside the function. I am editing my code assuming you want the `path` as an argument.

Comment: Folder_name is replaced with the input (name of relevant folder) when calling the function.

Comment: So if your folder name is, say, `fdname`, then you want to look inside `path/fdname`?

Comment: Yes. I want to look inside the folder and list the file names of the subfolder and also the contents of the subfolder. The output should be in the format provided above.

Comment: I have made a new edit. See if it is what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However, I don't understand the "Folder_name" argument in the object "newpath". I feel the "path" argument already provides access to the folder. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I suggest to improve your question by writing `My_file` as a function of the argument `Folder_name`. Your `My_file` function has an argument `Folder_name` which is nowhere used inside the function, so it is unclear where you want to use it.

Comment: Hi, the "Folder_name" is just a reference for me to call the function. For example, if the folder name is "Cars then I'll call the function using My_file (Cars). Thanks

Comment: How do you return the function using the code you provided? can you kindly provide some clarity on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `recursive = TRUE` in `list.files` -

```
My_file <- function (Folder_name) {
  My_list <- list.files(path = "/Users/user/Desktop/task/Data/Data", recursive = TRUE)
  return(My_list)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but it returns the directory of the files. Is there a way to only return the file names?

Comment: Sure, change `return(My_list)` to `return(basename(My_list))`

Comment: Thanks that works too but the output is not in the format required. I want the output in the form                                             

$House (subfolder name)


Bungalow.extension (file inside subfolder)